# Proving that a process is a Markov Chain using induction method.

Tags: probability, proof-writing, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, conditional-probability

Suppose that we are going to prove that a stochastic process $\{X_n\}$ is a Markov Chain. We have to show that:
$$Pr(X_k=i_k |X_{k-1}=i_{k-1},X_{k-2}=i_{k-2},...,X_{0}=i_{0}) = Pr(X_k=i_k|X_{k-1}=i_{k-1})$$

We are using induction method and suppose we have shown that the equation above holds for k = 2. We assume that it holds for k = n-2 as well. Now we have to show that it holds for k=n to complete the proof.

$$=Pr(X_n=i_n |X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_{n-2}=i_{n-2},...,X_{0}=i_{0}) \\
= \frac{Pr(X_n=i_n,X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_{n-2}=i_{n-2},...,X_{0}=i_{0})}{Pr(X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_{n-2}=i_{n-2},...,X_{0}=i_{0}) }\\
= \frac{Pr(X_n=i_n,X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_{n-2}=i_{n-2}|X_{n-3}=i_{n-3},...,X_{0}=i_{0})}{Pr(X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_{n-2}=i_{n-2}|X_{n-3}=i_{n-3},...,X_{0}=i_{0}) }\\$$

By assumption this is true:

$$Pr(X_{n-2}=i_{n-2} |X_{n-3}=i_{n-3},...,X_{0}=i_{0}) = Pr(X_{n-2}=i_{n-2} |X_{n-3}=i_{n-3})$$

Question here is that can we do this transformation:

$$= Pr(X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_{n-2}=i_{n-2}|X_{n-3}=i_{n-3},...,X_{0}=i_{0})\\
= Pr(X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_{n-2}=i_{n-2}|X_{n-3}=i_{n-3})  $$

Comment: Are you doing induction on the number of steps back in time you go, or induction on the final time?

Comment: @Ian On number of steps